# Writing a node with various types to file

Tags: java, file-io

I have a LinkedList containing nodes with the following attributes: `(int, String, String, String, double)` and I want to write all of the nodes in the list to a file containing all of the information. So far I have the following:

```
try (BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++){
                br.write(list.get(i)); //this line is the one in question
                br.newLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file " + file.toString());
        }//end catch
```

But I have no idea how to transpose the node into a file. I've tried casting the whole thing to a String, but I get errors running that as well. Is there a better way to do this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement the `toString()` in your node class.

```
public class Node{
    //....


    int foo; 
    String bar, qoo, yar;
    double baz;

    public String toString(){
        //print out your fields here.
    }    


    //....

}
```

And then call it in your write:

```
br.write(list.get(i).toString()); //this line is the one in question
```

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense. But I already have the toString in my node class printing out a customized display with all of the fields, so that display is what would be added to the file then right?

Comment: So my only issue with that is I will want to read the nodes from the file back into the list at a later time and that would alter the node. You can't have 2 toStrings right?

Comment: @user3524177  You can have as many as you want, just don't name it `toString()`. Name it `toFile()` and do the same thing.